# How to efficiently remove columns from a sparse matrix that only contain zeros?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

What is the best way to efficiently remove columns from a sparse matrix that only contain zeros. I have a matrix which I have created and filled with data:

```
matrix = sp.sparse.lil_matrix((100, 100))
```

I now wish to remove ~ the last 20 columns which only contain zero data. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you committed to using lil_matrix?  According to the scipy docs, it's not efficient for column slicing -- you might consider csc_matrix instead.  See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html and http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, csr or csc is also fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this were just a numpy array, `X`, then you could say `X!=0` which would give you a boolean array of the same shape as `X`, and then you could index `X` with the boolean array, i.e. `non_zero_entries = X[X!=0]`

But this is a sparse matrix which does not support boolean indexing and also will not give you what you want if you try `X!=0` -- it just returns a single boolean value that seems to only return true if they are the exact same matrix (in memory).

What you want is the `nonzero` method from numpy.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

X = sparse.lil_matrix((100,100)) # some sparse matrix
X[1,17] = 1
X[17,17] = 1
indices = np.nonzero(X) # a tuple of two arrays: 0th is row indices, 1st is cols
X.tocsc()[indices] # this just gives you the array of all non-zero entries
```

If you want only the full columns where there are non-zero entries, then just take the 1st from indices. Except you need to account for the repeated indices (if there are more than one entries in a column):

```
columns_non_unique = indices[1]
unique_columns = sorted(set(columns_non_unique))
X.tocsc()[:,unique_columns]
```

Comment: I used the following to extract just the columns with nonzero entries:  `matrix[:,np.unique(alldata.nonzero()[1])]`

Comment: That's nice and compact. Pretty much the same, except you use numpy's unique instead of `sorted(set(columns))`.

Comment: just to be clear, most sparse matrices have a `.nonzero` method that works in the same way, and much faster than `np.nonzero(sparse_matrix)`. Helpful answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the way, although not ideally efficient:

```
matrix = matrix[0:100,0:80]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the number of zero columns is not always fixed. I need a way to do this such that if there were 35 zero columns or 10 zero columns the program would still work.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use 
    `scipy.sparse.find()`
to get the locations of all nonzero elements in the sparse matrix.

The `[1]`th entry in the returned value is a numpy array of column numbers. Taking the unique values from this array gives the indices of the nonzero columns. Subsetting the original sparse matrix by these columns gives us the nonzero columns.

```
x[:,np.unique(sparse.find(x)[1])]
```

One can extend this to find columns with **at least n** entries:

```
idx = np.unique(sparse.find(x)[1], return_counts=True)
x[:, idx[0][idx[1] > n]]
```